# MAX keyword with criteria builder

Tags: java, criteria-api

I'm building a SELECT clause using CriteriaBuilder and I'm trying to achieve the following executed SQL when it's all said and done:

```
STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),columnName), ', ')
```

Current code:

```
cb.function(
    "STRING_AGG",
    String.class, 
    cb.function(
        "CONVERT",
        String.class,
        cb.function("NVARCHAR", Object.class, cb.literal(4000)),
        //columnName expression
    ),
    cb.literal(", ")
)
```

Yields:

```
STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),columnName), ', ')
```

How can I make the query use the `MAX` keyword instead of the literal `4000` as the argument for `NVARCHAR`?